# Badges for New Design

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

Thanks for the new design, Jin.

The badges appear to be cut off, with some names not showing up on them at all in FF 1.5.

Answer (score 2):

@justkt, for older browsers I don't try to make the design pixel perfect, as long as it's functional. Is there any reason why you're not using a newer browser? I assume it wasn't a typo when you said "FF 1.5"

Comment: at the moment, I'm on a system where I can't upgrade.

Comment: on Safari 4 it is working correctly, so must be an old browser thing.

Comment: consider a recent [portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) version, even w/o access to change the system